# Placing a shorter tab charachter in vba

Tags: excel, vba, tabs

I'm currently writing an output to a msgbox in vba which will give me a table of numbers. I understand i can use a VBTab to insert a tab into strings & VBCrLf for new lines.

The problem is that VBTabs are very large and i'm only working with strings of 1 to 3 characters, this causes a lot of wasted space and a huge textbox for only 50 or so numbers.

Is there a similar functions that will allow for me to align a table in a msgbox or a string in general?

Thanks.

Comment: Check the [Space function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278869.aspx). Perhaps adjusted by the Len function

Comment: You cannot change the tab size and spaces will prevent accurate alignment.  Consider using a Userform instead, then you can make it look however you like using multiple labels or a single label with a fixed width font.- http://gregmaxey.mvps.org/word_tip_pages/custom_vba_msgbox.html

Comment: I was hoping to dynamically allocate a number of spaces to each number to make them all lign up. I Know that the max length of the  numbers will be 3, but i don't know how many numbers there will be, meaning i cant use a user form display unless i put it into a scalable element..

Answer (score 0):

I use this padspace function to dynamically align column on text reports.  It might work for you.

```
Public Function PadSpace(nMaxSpace As Integer, nNumSpace As Integer) As String
    If nMaxSpace < nNumSpace Then
        PadSpace = ""
    Else
        PadSpace = Space(nMaxSpace - nNumSpace)
    End If
End Function
```

You call it by sending the column width and the length of the value you are putting into the column

```
strRow = strRow & "Total" & PadSpace(3, Len("Total"))
```

This will return the value with a number of spaces padded behind it.  You can also use it in front.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the LSET, RSET and SPACE$(n) keywords.

Basically you create some fixed length fields with SPACE(n) and then left or right set (justify) your data into those fields, concatenate your fields to form a record.  You must use a fixed width font such as Courier for everything to line up OK.